# Not receiving fcm message when app is close in Android with react-native-firebase

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

I followed the steps mentioned [here](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.2.x/messaging/receiving-messages).

Now, I'm receiving messages when the app is in foreground via firebase.messaging().onMessage and in the background, via a headless task I defined according to the same guide, but I don't receive messages when the app is closed

I am using one plus 6, where I even disabled the Battery optimize option for my phone, tried installing a signing build but none of it is working.

This is my `bgMessaging.js`

```
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';
// Optional flow type
import type { RemoteMessage } from 'react-native-firebase';

export default async (message: RemoteMessage) => {

    const channel = new firebase.notifications.Android.Channel('channel-id', 'channel-Name', firebase.notifications.Android.Importance.Max)
    .setDescription('Description');
    firebase.notifications().android.createChannel(channel);

    const localNotification = new firebase.notifications.Notification()
    .setNotificationId(message.messageId)
    .setTitle("Title")
    .setSubtitle('Test')
    .setBody("Body")
    .setData(message.data)
    .android.setChannelId('channel-id')
    .android.setAutoCancel(false)
    .android.setPriority(firebase.notifications.Android.Priority.High);

  firebase.notifications().displayNotification(localNotification);

    return Promise.resolve();
}
```

Even added this on AndroidManifest.xml

`<service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseBackgroundMessagingService" />`

Am I missing anything on native side?

Answer (score 0):

You can go to http://pushtry.com/ and set the jSON as :

```
{
 "to":FCM_TOKEN
 "notification": {
    "body": "body",
    "title": "title"
    },
 "priority":'high'
}
```